# what map tile numbering system has two tiles at level 0?

Tags: tiles

I have a set of map tiles that follow the typical quad tree format however, at level 0 (zoomed all the way out), I have two tiles instead of the expected 1. The tiles also follow a {z}/{y}/{x} numbering system. What is this system called?  I don't see this format listed on [Wikipedia - Tile Web Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map). I need a name to help find internet search results.

This is what I have for level 0.

- 0/0/0.png
- 0/0/1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the "World CRS84 Quad TileMatrixSet" from the OGC standard https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/17-083r2/17-083r2.html#63